# JSF SelectItem exception

Tags: exception, jsf

I am trying to give a list of SelectItems to a `selectOneMenu` and I am getting this exception :

```
[Ljavax.faces.model.SelectItem; cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
```

which looks kind of weird to me. This is the code in the page:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.name}">
                <f:selectItem value="#{user.names}" />  
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in User class:

```
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
private final SelectItem[] users = {new SelectItem("Jack"),new SelectItem("Max")};
```

Comment: What if you use `<f:selectItems/>` instead? It seems to me that `user.names` contains a list of names.

Comment: The exception message is not weird. The `[L` part means that it's an object array. You cannot cast `SelectItem[]` to `SelectItem`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am new with JSF so I didn't recognise that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<f:selectItem>` represents a single `SelectItem`, but your EL-expression feeds it an array of `SelectItems`. Did you mean `<f:selectItems>`?

Also, since JSF 2.x `f:selectItems` is quite capable of working with ordinary Java Beans, as the [official docs](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/) show:

```
<h:selectOneListbox size="1" id="escape02" value="#{select05NoSelection.initialCollectionValues}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{select05NoSelection.hobbitList}"
                 var="n"
                 itemValue="#{n}"
                 itemLabel="#{n.bio}"
                 itemDescription="#{n.description}"
                 itemDisabled="#{n.disabled}"
                 itemLabelEscaped="true"
                 noSelectionValue="#{select05NoSelection.hobbitList[0]}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

It is therefore no longer necessary to create SelectItems in the backing bean.